# Liferay Web-Service: method in *LocalServiceImpl not getting build in *LocalServiceUtil

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

Methods I am defining in *LocalServiceImpl is not getting defined by service builder in *LocalServiceUtil.

Have gone through this question,but didn't work for me
[Liferay: Any method written in *LocalServiceImpl not found in *LocalServiceUtil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260270/liferay-any-method-written-in-localserviceimpl-not-found-in-localserviceutil)

service log:

```
build-service:
 [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
 [echo] 8 Jun, 2015 8:18:28 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
 [echo] INFO: Global shared lib directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/lib/
 [echo] 8 Jun, 2015 8:18:28 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
 [echo] INFO: Global lib directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/
 [echo] 8 Jun, 2015 8:18:28 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
 [echo] INFO: Portal lib directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
 [echo] 8 Jun, 2015 8:18:28 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
 [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
 [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
 [echo] INFO: Properties for portal loaded from [file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties, jar:file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties, jar:file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties]
 [echo] Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
 [echo] Building SampleWS3
 [echo] Writing /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service/com/test3/model/SampleWS3Wrapper.java
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
compile-java:
 [copy] Copied 6 empty directories to 6 empty directories under /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
[javac] Compiling 18 source files to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
[zip] Building zip: /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib/SampleWs3-portlet-service.jar
[delete] Deleting directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/SampleWs3-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

stack-trace on deployment:

```
10:38:15,134 INFO   [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner]   [AutoDeployDir:177] Processing SampleWs3-portlet-6.1.1.1.war
10:38:15,135 INFO     [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner]    [PortletAutoDeployListener:77] Copying portlets for    /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-   ga2/deploy/SampleWs3-portlet-6.1.1.1.war
10:38:15,135 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:763] Deploying SampleWs3-portlet-6.1.1.1.war
10:38:15,173 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:859] Updating SampleWs3 from version 6.1.1.1 to version 6.1.1.1
Expanding: /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/deploy/SampleWs3-portlet-6.1.1.1.war into /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174
Copying 1 file to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174/WEB-INF
Copying 1 file to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174/WEB-INF/classes
Copying 1 file to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174/WEB-INF/classes
Copying 1 file to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174/WEB-INF/jsp
10:38:15,308 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:2083] Modifying Servlet 2.5 /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174/WEB-INF/web.xml
  Copying 102 files to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th   may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/SampleWs3-portlet
  Copying 1 file to /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/SampleWs3-portlet
  Deleting directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/20150608103815174
10:38:15,355 INFO    [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner]  [PortletAutoDeployListener:87] Portlets for /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle   20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/deploy/SampleWs3-portlet-6.1.1.1.war copied successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.
8 Jun, 2015 10:38:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/SampleWs3-portlet]
10:38:20,787 INFO    [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][PluginPackageUtil:1033] Reading plugin package for SampleWs3-portlet
8 Jun, 2015 10:38:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext  log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
8 Jun, 2015 10:38:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/rayon/shi/liferay bundle 20th may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/SampleWs3-portlet
10:38:21,573 INFO  [pool-2-thread-22][HotDeployImpl:178] Deploying SampleWs3-portlet from queue
10:38:21,574 INFO  [pool-2-thread-22][PluginPackageUtil:1033] Reading plugin package for SampleWs3-portlet
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/portlet.properties
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/service.properties
10:38:21,710 INFO  [pool-2-thread-22][ServiceComponentLocalServiceImpl:280] Upgrading Sample database to build number 62
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/portlet.properties
8 Jun, 2015 10:38:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/service.properties
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/service.properties
Loading file:/home/rayon/shi/liferay%20bundle%2020th%20may/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp/35-SampleWs3-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/portlet.properties
```

Comment: Can you please share you stack trace on deploy/runtime?

Comment: @Gevatterjan added in question, please check

Comment: Actually, I still do not see any errors. Have you tried to issue a clean command before building your new Service Layer? Also sometimes it can be a little bit weird if you change packages. Please try do undeploy the portlet, do a clean -> build of the service and portlet, and try a deploy on a system where the portlet is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Check the sourcecode for your `*LocalServiceUtil` and make sure it really doesn't have the method's implementation. If the method is there, you'll have to look elsewhere. Here's where:

When you deploy a portlet, you can get the API on multiple ways: Someone might have deployed the plugin containing the services on tomcat's global class path. If you don't update *that one*, you probably won't see your updates.

Also, someone might have copied an older version of your plugin into their own plugin as well - naturally not seeing any updates unless they update their dependency. Check for changed names of the jar file as well. Also check for the classes: Some people like to add the compiled java classes to their source directories, ending up with two different implementations of the same code.